# RavenDb Make computations during query

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I have read a lot of times that RavenDb doesn't do any computation during query time. For example here is the quote from Ayende's article ["The Pain of Implementing LINQ Providers"](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2001564)

> One of the features of RavenDB is that it performs absolutely no
>   computation during queries; all the data for the query is already
>   prepared. That means that we can achieve very good querying speeds.

But at the same time there is Live Projections feature which allows to make some computations during query. For example, here I use sorting and sum calculation:

```
TransformResults = (database, post) => from post in posts
                                       order by post.DateTime
                                       select new
                                                {
                                                  Id = post.Id,
                                                  CommentsCount = post.Comments.Sum()
                                                }
```

So RavenDb allows to make computations on the fly, doesn't it?

**Update.** I decided to provide one more example where you actually have to compute (sort) things during query time. Task: select 10 last post comments for specific BlogId (assume we have a lot of blogs on our blogging system):

```
public class LastPostsCommentsIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post>
{
    public class IndexResult
    {
        public string BlogId {get; set;}
    }

    public class PostComment
    {
        public string PostId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public LastPostsCommentsIndex()
    {
        Map = posts => from post in posts
                       select new { BlogId = post.BlogId };

        TransformResults = (database, posts) => from post in posts
                                                from comment in post.Comments
                                                orderby comment.DateTime descending
                                                select new { PostId = post.Id, DateTime = comment.DateTime, Author = comment.Author, Text = comment.Text };
    }
}
```

In this case we are not able to sort Map index results - we have to sort results on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. But this is nit picking, isn't it?

When someone speaks about "computation" in this context, it is computation (like Sum, Avg, Count) across several documents, what is meant.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify it. Actually I am not sure whether it is possible to make some more heavier, cross-documents computation during TransformResults.

Comment: I thought about it a bit more. At least I can do sorting on TransformResults.

Comment: Hm, not sure I understand what you mean by "sorting on TransformResults".

Comment: I have modified the example in the question. Please take a look

Comment: I have added one more sample in Update

Comment: Ok, but _what_ is the question?

Comment: I just was surprised about it and wanted to clarify with somebody who knows RavenDb better. Yep, may be it is not appropriate question for SO

Comment: I agree with Daniel, it's not doing computations that affect **which** docs are returned the query itself. It's just changing the **shape** of the docs that come out, there's a subtle difference. Also the computation can only work one 1 doc at a time, not across docs.

Comment: @MattWarren, I can't agree with you. AsProjections just changes the shape of the docs, but live projections is a bit more than that: it can compute, sort, etc. And about "1 doc at a time"... are you sure we can't execute some groupby inside TransformResults?

Comment: Okay, my comment was slightly wrong. You can pull in another doc from the database using `database.Load<T>(..)`, so technically you could do grouping inside `TransformResult`. But if you want to do grouping, that's what the `Reduce` part of the index is for.

Comment: Thank you guys for discussion. I will mark this answer as accepted, but I still think it not correct to say that "RavenDb performs absolutely no computation during query time" (while I would agree with "every RavenDb query is executed on an index")